# HTML: How to Use href in class attribute of an element

Tags: html, css

I saw an unusual thing in This Website: 
[AccuWeather.com](http://www.accuweather.com/en/ca/toronto/m5g/weather-forecast/55488)
Some tags in this page (like `li`s) have a `href` with a url in its `Class` attribute, Like the picture below,
So what I want to know is:

1- Why they used the `href` and `url` in class attribute?

2- how can I do this?

[ScreenShot http://4ax.ir/images/screenaja.jpg](http://4ax.ir/images/screenaja.jpg).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's nothing special. They're just using JSON encoding to put arbitrary data into a DOM element. An alternative to use to the new `data-` attributes allowed by HTML5.

Why do you want to do this? Browsers will not treat it specially, and in fact JSON-encoded data makes it an invalid attribute value.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Why they used the href and url in class attribute?

They did this mainly on `li` elements. I guess this has been done in order to provide the data to an event handler, in order to navigate to another page on a `click` or `mousedown` event.

> 2) How can I do this?

Basically they're storing a [JSON object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JSON) in the class name. One could extract the data with [`JSON.parse(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), but you shouldn't. Use the HTML5 `data-xxx` attributes instead.